# Cannot get json data using Phonegap on Android

Tags: jquery, json, cordova

I'm trying to create an app for Android connected to a database of a website.
I'm using phonegap, and I want to use JSON to get data back from the database to the app.

I created a php script on the server side to execute some sql requests, and form a valid json file.

I created the script to get the data, and it was working when I was running it in my browser (on my desktop), but now I'm trying to send the app on my mobile, it's not working anymore, it's like the json request is not doing anything.

I added the website in the whitelist in config.xml.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
 <script>
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    });
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

   document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
   function onDeviceReady() 
    {       
        var db = window.openDatabase("GalagoPosts", "1.0", "GalagoPosts", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    // Populate the database 
    //
    function populateDB(tx) 
    {
        //tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS GalagoTuto');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GalagoTuto (id unique, title TEXT NOT NULL, artist TEXT NOT NULL, difficulty INTEGER NOT NULL, date TEXT NOT NULL, link TEXT NOT NULL)');

        // Ajax request
        //
        $url = "http://www.mydomain.com/JSON/json_get_data.php";
        $.getJSON($url, function(data) 
                           {
                           alert("Got Data");
                           $.each(data, function(index, element) 
                                           {                                   
                                           $("#latest").append(element.Title+"<br/>");
                                           });
                           displayPages();
                           });  

    }

    // Transaction error callback
    //
    function errorCB(tx, err) 
    {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }

    // Transaction success callback
    //
    function successCB() 
    {
        //alert("Succes");
    }

    // Display main page after loading data
    //
    function displayPages() 
    {
        $("body .splashScreen").delay(10).fadeOut(10, function() {
        $("body .mainApp").fadeIn(10);
        $("#nav-bar .current_page_item a").mouseenter();
        });
    }
    </script>
```

and here is my php code:

```
 //echo $_GET['jsoncallback'].'('.json_encode($json_array).');';
   echo json_encode($json_array);
```

I tried with and without callback, but I never got the alert "Got Data".
I'm using Phonegap 3.4.0, jQuery 1.11.1, and jQuery mobile 1.4.2.

I spent a crazy amount of time trying to figure it out, searching on google, but in the end nothing worked on my mobile.

Does anyone has an idea how to do that ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure it out. I can't believe how stupid it is.

I used this code to include jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

But if you don't add this in your config.xml, it's not working:

```
<access origin="http://code.jquery.com" subdomains="true" />
```

I didn't think it was necessary to allow jquery.com on the whitelist.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
alert(data); //alert("Got Data");
```

if it gives the  alert with json data

Check in that alert for `Title` It works code is fine.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. Just curious, why would alert(data) work if alert("Got data") is not ?

Comment: that alert() will show the json content received from server. If blank is coming in alert so no response from server, If alert is not coming then some error in the code. You paste the same code in consoel(F12) chrome or firefox